# Memory management issue with string in CPP

Tags: c++, string, memory-management

I am trying to seperate strings that are filled with ' ' and store that in array. For that I wrote code,

```
string* componentsOfStringSeperatedBystring(string originalString, string stringCompare){

string *arryOfStrings=NULL;

string *tempArrayString = NULL;
for (int i=0; i<originalString.length(); i++) {


    size_t position = originalString.find(stringCompare);
    cout << "\nposition" <<position;

    if (position == originalString.npos) {

        break;
    }
    size_t subStringLength = originalString.length() - position;

    cout << "\nsubStringLength" <<subStringLength;
    string subString = originalString.substr(0,position);

    cout << "\nsubString" <<subString;

    tempArrayString = (string*)realloc(arryOfStrings, (i+1)*sizeof(string));

    cout << "\n i \t" <<i;
    if (tempArrayString != NULL) {

        arryOfStrings = tempArrayString;
        arryOfStrings[i] = subString;
    }


    cout << "\narryOfStrings" <<arryOfStrings;
    originalString = originalString.substr(position+1,subStringLength);
}

return arryOfStrings;
}
```

I am getting crashed on line "arryOfStrings[i] = subString;", If I simply allocate enough space first, and then without reallocating, I am not getting crashed.

Comment: The first thing to do is to use `std::vector` instead of that pointer  array you have going on there.

Comment: +1 @chris why would some one use pointers to string and realloc…

Comment: @rakeshNS how do you mean `seperate strings that are filled with ' ' `? Do you mean separate string by ' ' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use C-style memory management on C++-style objects. Either go fully C-style (use null-terminated `char*` strings) or go fully C++-style (use `std::vector<std::string>`).

Comment: I used std::vector<std::string>, and now it is working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `new` with `std::string` not c memory allocation functions.
They do not call constructors for `std::string` class unlike `new`. And the constructor for `std::string` class needs to be called for its proper initialization.

To be honest you shouldn't be using `std::string *` at all. In doing so You lose all the advantages that were gained in avoiding using `char *` to begin with. Simply use:

```
std::vector<std::string>
```